# How to convert string to integer when we have comma (,) in between word when used in java code

Tags: java, string, integer, number-formatting, parseint

I am trying to convert a price amount 3,456 which is in string datatype to integer data type. But I'm getting a number format exception error. I have tried `parseInt` method and `valueOf` but giving same error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String name="3,456";
int value= Integer.parseInt(name);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

[here is the error in console after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osiv5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is the comma `,` mandatory in your data? Can't you leave it away? If the comma is really there, and those are really integers, just try `name.replace(",","")` to remove and then use `parseInt` on that.